# Por qué muestra undefined

Tags: javascript

Obtengo los elemenentos con la clase `'link'`, pero me devuelve **undefined** cuando los recorro con `for of`, por qué?

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',() => {
var elementos = document.getElementsByClassName('link');
  
for(var j of elementos) { console.log(elementos[j]) }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

    <a href='link1' class="link"></a>
    <a href='link2' class="link"></a>
    <a href='link3' class="link"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si usas `for (var elem of iterable) {...}`, elem no es el identificador, sino el elemento. Te estás confundiendo con `for (var i in object) {...}`

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',() => {
  var elementos = document.getElementsByClassName('link');
  for(var j of elementos) { 
    console.log(j);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href='link1' class="link"></a>
    <a href='link2' class="link"></a>
    <a href='link3' class="link"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Estás haciendo mal uso del `for...of`.

> La sentencia **for...of** crea un bucle que itera a través de los elementos de objetos iterables (incluyendo Array, Map, Set, el objeto arguments, etc.), ejecutando las sentencias de cada iteración con el valor del elemento que corresponda.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',() => {
var elementos = document.getElementsByClassName('link');
  
for(var j of elementos) {
  console.log(j);
}

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

    <a href='link1' class="link"></a>
    <a href='link2' class="link"></a>
    <a href='link3' class="link"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Referencia:**

- [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...of)

Answer (score 1):

La instrucción es `for ... in` no `for ... of`:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',() => {
var elementos = document.getElementsByClassName('link');
  
for(var j in elementos) { console.log(elementos[j]) }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

    <a href='link1' class="link"></a>
    <a href='link2' class="link"></a>
    <a href='link3' class="link"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No creo que sea así, porque hay una respuesta algo parecido en la comunidad de habla inglesa, que dice que no debe usarse for/in(la respuesta mas votada)    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754315/for-loop-for-htmlcollection-elements   , sino corrigeme